# Google maps not working in Firefox with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, firefox

https://github.com/sketchman2017/fun-box-level-2/commits/master

I saw this issue [GoogleMaps does not load on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466718/googlemaps-does-not-load-on-page-load) and I applyed it. But after adding adaptive design (see commit f96..) from bootstrap it is not working now in Firefox. Console said: "InvalidValueError: window.initMap is not a function". In Chrome all works. Where I wrong?

Comment: include app.js script after <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkYZgRyS-pS5Cu7gUU4_6xp5HNxgo0cX4&callback=initMap"
 +    async defer></script>

Comment: Works but then not works.

Comment: Without code or fiddle how we can help you?

Comment: Can you tell me, is bootstrap grid more flexible then flexbox? I think that I need to write this code myself without 3-party librarieslike bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I changes jquery version from 3.3.1. to 2.2.4 and placed script tag with jquery at the top of the head as here [JQuery and Google Maps JS api not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252828/jquery-and-google-maps-js-api-not-working-together). Working.